# I can't edit anything in my disk

Tags: paste, mkdir

I install Ubuntu latest version by formatting my windows( New volume:C) so that there is no data lose of my other disc. But now I can't delete/create a new folder/paste in this disc. Please tell me any solution of this. I also tried "sudo mkdir New_Folder" in terminal, but it won't work.

Comment: It is unclear. Do you have a working linux already?

Comment: Please be specific as to what you mean. Latest version means? The latest release is Ubuntu 21.04 but do you mean desktop? server? or even a *cloud* or IoT product like Ubuntu Core 20?  or do you mean a much older but latest LTS such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop? or Server?  ie. please be specific.  Also what message(s) did you get with the `sudo mkdir New_Folder` as it's best if we see the command, your $PWD (present working directory) & resulting error message; which are useful clues as to your issue (we don't know what your $PWD is as if it was in /dev/ you cannot create devices that way..)

Comment: @guiverc @MaestroGlanz Thanks for your reply... Basically I am a beginner in linux. Can u pls recommend me any site or youtube video for learning linux (**Ubuntu**) and all its `sudo` command and their uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to create a new folder using the terminal, and it shows that the disc is **read-only** for use, I apply the following and it's is sorted.

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/drive_name
```

The drive name can be seen by executing the command: `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: You need to understand the Windows Fast Startup feature and what it does to any NTFS partitions it has access to. Basically, if you had disabled it as recommended everywhere and shutdown Windows properly before removing it, this wouldn't have happened.